# Material with particle info node location is not working as expected

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

[image]

I'm trying to discriminate the lower particles from the higher particles on the z axis, but the particle info location makes it very random.

Half of the particles are about z=0, so I expect a smooth gradient from bottom to top, but it isn't the case. This is in blender 2.9. Thanks.

Blender file:
https://easyupload.io/vufyr0

Comment: What happens when you change the values on the colour ramp?

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Comment: Provided a link to the .blend file.

Comment: The condition sort of works, but it's working a bit fuzzy i.e. I expect it to be a very gradient but right now it sort of work like a percentage over the entire volume...